# Can I navigate from one fragment (fragment1) to another (fragment2) through a button which is on fragment1?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I am having trouble to navigate from one fragment to another through a button in my android application. I have considered several questions about this issue but the solutions provided are not solving my problem. Here is my code and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
public class fragment_profile extends Fragment {

TextView txtFname, txtLname, txtGender, txtAge, txtPhone, txtEmail;
Button btImages, btVideos;
ImageButton btProfilePic;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);


    btProfilePic = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.ProfilePic);

    txtFname = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvFName);
    txtLname = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvLName);
    txtGender = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvGender);
    txtAge = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvAge);
    txtPhone = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvPhone);
    txtEmail = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvEmail);

    btImages = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnImages);
    btVideos = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnVideos);


    //The code to replace fragment is not good, the clicklistener is working fine as I have tested it with a toast message

    btImages.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            //An object of the fragment tree is created
            fragmentImages ImageGallery = new fragmentImages();
            //The fragment is finally added
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_profile, ImageGallery, "Image Gallery").commit();
            //Set title of action bar = title of fragment
            getActivity().setTitle(getTag());
        }
    });

    btVideos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            //An object of the fragment tree is created
            fragmentVideos VideoGallery = new fragmentVideos();
            //The fragment is finally added
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_profile, VideoGallery, "Video Gallery").commit();
            //Set title of action bar = title of fragment
            getActivity().setTitle(getTag());
        }
    });


    return rootView;
}
}
```

The issue is with the code inside the `onClickListener`. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Is this R.id.fragment_profile part of your fragment layout or main activity layout ?

Comment: This tutorial may be useful.  http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: @Rohit5k2 When I click on the Buttons it just change the title (Which is currently "Profile") to nothing ("Profile just disappear"). And nothing happens

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you :) I will go through it and give you feedback :)

Comment: @penguin thank you mate. My first mistake is "R.id.fragment_profile" is not the id of my main activity layout. My second mistake is  `getFragmentManager` . I was not able to use `getSupportFragmentManager` because I didn't write `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager`
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `supportFragmentManager`. Within your `onClickListener`(s), make your transaction this:

```
//An object of the fragment tree is created
fragmentImages ImageGallery = new fragmentImages();

getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_profile, ImageGallery).commit();

//rest of your setting the activity title below
```

It is also best practise to make write your classes like `FragmentImages` and then your variables as `imageGallery` for example or even `fragmentImages` so you know what the object is.

Comment: Should be mentioned that `R.id.fragment_profile` needs to be the id of the container in the Activity XML where the Fragments are shown

Comment: @cricket_007 yes that's right, I forgot to mention that!

Comment: Thank you for the reply :) Yeah I don't know why android studio is not allowing me to use `getSupportManager` although I am using the Support Library :/

Comment: @Jamill Check your imports. You need to import the correct support Fragment class, not `android.app.Fragment`

Comment: It's okay :) you need to use getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager() to use the support library, otherwise you can only access the non-support fragment manager but let's be honest, no one usually uses that!

Comment: Hey guys thank you very much. You solved my problem. Firstly @cricket_007 That the id should be that of the container, which I changed. Then @TomAlabaster suggested `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager` and I changed this also. Now everything is working fine. Thank you guys I appreciate :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add your `fragment_profile` fragment to the backstack so you can recall it afterwards after you have triggered the other fragments. Try the following:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_profile, ImageGallery, "Image Gallery").addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Same with the latter:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_profile, VideoGallery, "Video Gallery").addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

I got the information from here: [Fragment Replacing Existing Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227400/fragment-replacing-existing-fragment)

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your help :) I did try it but nothing :/